# Web Bluetooth API cannot find my device (Google Pixel 7 phone)

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I am testing web bluetooth API from chrome.
I understood that web bluetooth API support for chrome and BLE devices.
My device bluetooth version is 5.2 ,android version is 13 and I am using window 10. I thought that bluetooth 5.2 support BLE.
I already enable in chrome flexs of web experimental.
But, when I try with this code

```
let device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    acceptAllDevices: true,
    optionalServices: [ 0x180D ]
    });
    let server = await device.gatt.connect();
    console.log(server);
    let service = await server.getPrimaryService(0x180D);
    console.log(service);
```

my pixel 7 phone's bluetooth name or device name does not appear in device list.

I already check my device from chrome internal.

> chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices

But, my phone bluetooth address does not appear.

What is wrong in my code?
Is this the problem of Pixel 7 side or chrome side?
Does pixel 7 support BLE?

Comment: By default your phone does not advertise as BLE device. To be able to find your device you must run any GATT server or any BLE advertising software on it. Then you can find it.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko thank you for your answer. I am trying to install BLE peripheral simulator(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral) from google play store, but the app does not fit with my android version. Is any other app you know or any other ways?

Comment: I recommend the nRF Connect app from Nordic as you can easily use it to advertise your device. Once installed, go to the Advertiser tab and add a new device with any arbitrary name.

Comment: I installed it but I still can't find my device name in web bluetooth of device list.

Comment: @EiThantarWin  Are you sure your device advertises the 0x180D service? I actually do not think so. You can try BeaconWatcher and GattClient demo applications from Bluetooth Framework to check what your device advertises.

Comment: Now, I can find my device name in chrome bluetooth internal but when I clicked "inspect" of the selected device, the device name change to "Unknown or Unsupported device" and cann't connect.

Comment: @EiThantarWin I guess it is because you simple start advertising on your phone, but did not start GATT server. You can connect to GATT server only. More about GATT: https://www.btframework.com/gatt.htm